# Animation of Back-Button broken after dismiss of Modal View Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, back-button, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm having a very very strange issue here. I have an App with a Tabbar Controller and 4 Tabs, each of them has a Navigation Controller hooked up to a Viewcontroller. Everything worked as it should, but now I have added a button to a couple of Views, which invokes a Modal View Controller to slide up and show some content. Within this Modal VC there's another button to hide the Modal View. 
After the Modal View gets hidden, if I tap the back-button in my navigation bar, the view doesn't animate back but just shows the previous view instantly without animation, while the navigation bar is indeed animated. But when I use the tab bar to switch to another View and immediately switch back, it suddenly starts working again.

I'm using iOS SDK 6 without Storyboards, since I have developed this app back on iOS 3.2 a few years ago

This is how I'm showing the Modal VC:

```
-(void)reportIssue{
    ReportIssueViewController *rivc = [[ReportIssueViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReportIssueViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:rivc animated:TRUE];
    [rivc release];
}
```

And this is how I'm hiding it:

```
- (IBAction)cancelIssue:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:NULL];
}
```

Has anyone ever had such a strange issue like this??? 
I would be happy about any ideas on how to get rid of this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One cause I've seen of behavior like this was not calling super in viewDidAppear (maybe in viewDidLoad and/or viewDidDisappear also).

Comment: Yes, it was missing in a couple of Viewcontrollers but adding these super-calls didn't help :-(

Comment: You have been right!!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. I had subclassed the UITabbarController and I have added a `-(void)viewWillAppear`-function where I have put some logic. Unfortunately I forgot to add the `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` call inside of that function. Very stupid mistake.

Thanks to rdelmar, who pointed out the possible cause for this in the first comment of my question.

Comment: OMG I can't believe it just happened to me again

Comment: In my case it was `viewDidAppear`, but it had the same result. Bottom line: always make sure you delegate to super unless you explicitly don't want to.